# Do all the copies of Vedas found across India have the same content?

Tags: vedas

As Vedas didn't originate in written form and the manuscripts are created later by various persons, are all the manuscripts exactly the same?

Comment: I'm not asking what are the original vedas

Comment: The answer by @keshav has original version of Vedas. Your question will be broad as we are not sure about all copies of Vedas in entire India.

Comment: It is true that Vedas were transmitted through memory and hearing, but they were written down during Adi Shankaracharya's time. This version is the "untampered" one and is either with Germany (taken away by Hitler's army), the Britishers or the U.S.A. Most of the "translated" version has lies inserted and many things omitted.